# how to add data in html table in .net mvc view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

i **just want to add two columns dynamically to my table. using mvc razor**.. and this is my code below :-

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>delete</th>
    <th>modified</th>


    and for getting data to my table m using code like :-

    <tbody>
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows )
    {
    <tr>
    @foreach (var in cell in row.ItemArray)
    {
    if (cell ! = null)
    {
       <td>@cell.ToString()</td> 
    }
    else  {
       <td></td>
    }
    }
</tr>
}
<tbody>
</table>
```

now i just **want to add one link in both delete and modified columns for each rows.. thanks for any help**

Answer (score 1):

You can add buttons in columns after cells foreach cycle. I also sugest you to use a PartialView for button display but this depends on you. Below is the simple way of doing it. I also used some bootstrap classes.

```
  <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows )
        {
        <tr>
        @foreach (var in cell in row.ItemArray)
        {
        if (cell ! = null)
        {
           <td>@cell.ToString()</td> 
        }
        else  {
           <td></td>
        }
        }
    <td>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "ABC", new { id=Model.Id})" title="Edit ABC"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Details", "ABC", new { id=Model.Id })" title="Details of ABC"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></a></td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "ABC", new { id=Model.Id })" title="Delete this ABC"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add more cells after the inner loop:

```
<tr>
  @foreach (var in cell in row.ItemArray) {
    if (cell ! = null) {
     <td>@cell.ToString()</td> 
    } else {
     <td></td>
    }
  }
  <td>@* Render something at the end of the row*@</td>
</tr>
```